# Employee Manager must be able to access his & his own team's data

Tags: filter, odoo

in Odoo CRM i need to implement Record Rule from Odoo frontend (using Settings -> Technical -> Security -> Record Rules in Developer mode) as below:

1. logged-in user should see his/her data only or not assgined yet to a Saleperson.
2. a Manager can see his/her data plus including the related staff / subordinates data only

- crm.lead contains user_id (Saleperson)
- hr.employee contains parent_id (Manager)

hope the requirement is clear.

please help to write **Domain filter for Record Rule**.

regards